# Evaluating a determinant (What's the trick?)

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   1 & 2 & 3 &  \cdots  & {n - 1} & n  \\
   { - 1} & x & 0 &  \cdots  & 0 & 0  \\
   0 & { - 1} & x & 0 &  \cdots  & 0  \\
   0 & 0 & { - 1} & x &  \cdots  & 0  \\
   {} & {} & {} & {} &  \ddots  & {}  \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & { - 1} & x  \\
\end{array}} \right|$$

What's the proper "trick" for evaluating this determinant?
I tried couple of things which didn't work out.

Comment: Try using induction.

Comment: Your matrix isn't really well-defined. What is the matrix if $n=2$?

Comment: Have you tried by expanding of the first column?

Comment: Oh you right, I actually thought about it but somehow gave up on that. I'll continue with this direction.

Comment: I guess for $n=2$:  

$$\left| {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   1 & 2  \\
   { - 1} & x  \\
\end{array}} \right|$$

Comment: You will have to require $n>2$ because your matrix $A$ explicitly shows $a_{2n}=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your determinant is $D_n$, then $D_1=1$ and expansion along the last column gives $D_n=n+x D_{n-1}$. The solution of this recurrence is $D_n=n+(n-1)x+(n-2)x^2+\dots+2 x^{n-2}+1x^{n-1}$.

Comment: I see. There is no need to split the induction like I did.  
lets assume the assumption is true for the case of $n-1$. 
Can you help me with proving the $n$ case?

Comment: @AndrePoole: If $D_{n-1}=(n-1)+\dots+x^{n-2}$, then multiplying by $x$ shifts every power one step upwards, and then adding $n$ gives you the new constant term. So $n+xD_{n-1}$ matches the expression for $D_n$.